# Flow chart questions

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, flow-charts, tikz-path

I just started using LaTex and this is my first try on drawing a graph. I've encountered some problems and these are my questions:

1. May I know how can I position `M,Q` and `E` on the arrows "above" and "below" the arrow so that they are visible? (probably shorten the arrows ?)
2. How can I position the arrow in such a way that the `M,Q`arrows are going into the left portion of the node(box), and the `E`arrows are going out from the right portion of the node(box). [image]
3. How can I make a branch after `Operation` so that I can link it back to `Material production`.
4. How to position the `Recycling` node below and at the center of the two nodes `Operation` and `Treatment Disposal`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!20]

    \tikzstyle{arrow} = =[thick,->,>=stealth]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]
    \node (RMA) [startstop,minimum size=2cm] {\begin{varwidth}{2cm}Raw\\ Material\\ Acquisition\end{varwidth}};
    \node [above of = RMA, node distance = 2cm] (MQ1) {};
    \node [below of = RMA, node distance = 2cm] (E1) {};

    \node (MP) [startstop,minimum size=2cm, right of=RMA] {\begin{varwidth}{2.5cm}Material \\Production\end{varwidth}};
    \node [above of = MP, node distance = 2cm] (MQ2) {};
    \node [below of = MP, node distance = 2cm] (E2) {};


    \node (FD) [startstop,minimum size=2cm, right of=MP] {\begin{varwidth}{2.5cm}Film \\Deposition\end{varwidth}};
    \node [above of = FD, node distance = 2cm] (MQ3) {};
    \node [below of = FD, node distance = 2cm] (E3) {};

    \node (MP1) [startstop,minimum size=2cm, right of=FD] {\begin{varwidth}{2.5cm}Module \\Production\end{varwidth}};
    \node [above of = MP1, node distance = 2cm] (MQ4) {};
    \node [below of = MP1, node distance = 2cm] (E4) {};

    \node (O) [startstop,minimum size=2cm, right of=MP1] {\begin{varwidth}{2.5cm}Operation\end{varwidth}};
    \node [above of = O, node distance = 2cm] (MQ5) {};
    \node [below of = O, node distance = 2cm] (E5) {};

    \node (TD) [startstop,minimum size=2cm, right of=O] {\begin{varwidth}{2.5cm}Treatment\\Disposal\end{varwidth}};
    \node [above of = TD, node distance = 2cm] (MQ6) {};
    \node [below of = TD, node distance = 2cm] (E6) {};

    \node (R) [startstop,minimum size=2cm, below of=TD] {\begin{varwidth}{2.5cm}Recycling\end{varwidth}};



    \draw [arrow] (RMA) -- (MP);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MQ1) to node[above] {\small$M,Q$} (RMA);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (RMA) to node[below] {$E$} (E1);

    \draw [arrow] (MP) -- (FD); 
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MQ2) to node[above] {\small$M,Q$} (MP);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MP) to node[below] {$E$} (E2);

    \draw [arrow] (FD) -- (MP1);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MQ3) to node[above] {\small$M,Q$} (FD);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (FD) to node[below] {$E$} (E3);

    \draw [arrow] (MP1) -- (O);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MQ4) to node[above] {\small$M,Q$} (MP1);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MP1) to node[below] {$E$} (E4);

    \draw [arrow] (O) -- (TD);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MQ5) to node[above] {\small$M,Q$} (O);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (O) to node[below] {$E$} (E5);

    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (MQ6) to node[above] {\small$M,Q$} (TD);
    \draw[arrow, thick, dashed] (TD) to node[below] {$E$} (E6);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: completing your MWE might also attract answers ;)

Comment: Just did, didnt know how it works. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i combine your code and looks of provided image. of course, you can easily change node style (to rounded corners or to white fill):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning, shadows}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=14mm and 6mm,
start chain = going right,
          > = Stealth,
 arr/.style = {thick, - >},
 lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, xshift=-0.5pt},
 box/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
               minimum width=22mm, minimum height=12mm, align=center,
               drop shadow ={shadow xshift=-1ex, shadow yshift=-1ex},
               on chain, join=by arr,
   append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \draw[densely dashed,->] ([xshift= 7mm] \LN.south) -- + (0,-5mm) node[lbl,below] {E};
        \draw[densely dashed,<-] ([xshift=-7mm] \LN.north) -- + (0, 5mm) node[lbl] {M\,Q};
                    }}},
                        ]
\node (RMA) [box]   {Raw Material\\ Acquisition};
\node (MQ1) [box]   {Material \\Production};
\node (FD)  [box]   {Film \\Deposition};
\node (MP1) [box]   {Module \\Production};
\node (O)   [box]   {Operation};
\node (TD)  [box]   {Treatment\\Disposal};
\node (R)   [suppress join,box,
             below=of $(MQ1.south)!0.5!(TD.south)$] {Recycling};
%
\draw[arr]  ($(O.east)!0.5!(TD.west)$) |- (R);
\draw[arr]  (R) -| (MQ1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- for nodes positioning is used `tikz` library `chains`,
- connection between nodes are done by use of macro `join=by ...`
- suppress of the macro `join` for fit-back node is in preamble defined style `suppress join`
- parameters inputs and outputs are drawn as part of `box` node with

  ```
     append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
          \draw[densely dashed,->] ([xshift= 7mm] \LN.south) -- + (0,-5mm) node[lbl,below] {E};
          \draw[densely dashed,<-] ([xshift=-7mm] \LN.north) -- + (0, 5mm) node[lbl] {M\,Q};
  ```
- with all this changes the mwe (minimal working example) with your flowchart become quite shorter

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what i wanted.  Can you please let me know how can I change :

- the arrow of MQ to going into the node
- the arrow of MQ and E to be dashed

Comment: @thesilencer, i edit my answer. added are desired changes.